# Использование cron на хостинге для 3х последовательных задач

Tags: cron

Всех приветствую, спасибо что зашли

Есть хостинг, у которого есть функционал для запуска задач с выполнением их кроном ( планировка задач ) . Задачи выполняются через определенный период времени. Подскажите с командами. Хочется выполнять импорт данных из файла таблицы (лежит на хостинге) в бд сайта, в 3 этапа так сказать.

1. Как заставить проверять определенную директорию на хостинге на наличие файла? т.е. если файл есть - далее, если нет, то нет (обычный файл *.sql для таблицы mysql)
2. Импортируем файл *.sql в определенную таблицу mysql (просто переписать записи в нее, таблица изначально пустая)
3. После завершения импорта - запустить определенную страницу php

Comment: господа, некоторые отдельные команды для cron'а я нашел, и к сожалению сам в ужасе. вроде с одной стороны он все умеет, о чем нашел, а как начинаешь 'копать' - вот даже простой импорт, который возможен локально установленной программой, уже беда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой скрипт сохранить в файл script.sh, дать ему права на запуск и добавить в крон

```
# 1.if [ -f /path/to/file.sql ] then    # 2.    mysql < /path/to/file.sql    # если в mysql используется пароль, то    # mysql -p<пароль> < /path/to/file.sql    # 3.    php /path/to/page.phpfi
```

Comment: спасибо. пойду тестировать

Comment: Почти молодец, тока нормальные посаны еще пишут имя бд когда делают restore. Т.е mysql dbname < /path/to/file.sql.

Comment: конечно ) вот казалось, что что-то забыл.. опять ты меня выручаешь, пятак ))